# C++ debuggers for linux similar to MS Visual Studio's debugger?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

A little background: for a while I've been using a free IDE for my C++ projects named CodeBlocks. Recently I've got a licence for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and I've got to say it's a completely different experience. The auto-complete is better, sensitive and accurate error checking as you're typing, a visual resource manager for MFC applications. And while these things you can get in pretty much any text editor with the right plugins, what I found especially appealing about MS Visual Studio is its very nice and visually appealing debugger (way easier to use and provides more information than the one in CodeBlocks).

I've been thinking for a while to switch over to a linux-based system since, to me at least, it seems to provide better tools for general purpose programming. However, I just can't bring myself to losing the MS VS debugger and going back to something like the one in CodeBlocks. I've been searching for various debuggers for linux but I can't really find one similar to the one in MSVS2013. Can anybody help me with this? What is a good debugger that I can use?

Functionality that I'm looking for:

- an "Auto" watch tab/window which tracks variables that have been used recently or that are likely to be used, including a "this" pointer when inside class methods;
- a "Locals" watch tab/window which tracks strictly local variables (without having to input them manually)
- highlighting of variables that have changed when stepping from one instruction to another
- being able to set multiple Watch windows/tabs and easily switch between them
- being able to expand objects being watched in order to see their members' values
- being able to easily see the values stored at addresses which watched pointers are pointing to

Comment: Use a decent IDE like e.g. Eclipse CTD.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you aren't short of options.

The classic Linux debugger - gdb - has a command-line gui based on ncurses which is activated by launching with the -tui argument. Admittedly it's a little bit basic compared to IDE integration, but it's incredibly powerful.

A stand-alone GUI for gdb called ddd is popular in certain circles. The interface isn't particularly modern, but it supports the full range of gdb capabilities.

If you're looking for an integrated development environment, then Jetbrains CLion is a relative newcomer but features reasonable gdb integration. If you're looking for a free alternative then Eclipse CDT is fairly well integrated.

My personal favourite option is a commercial plugin called VisualGDB which integrates VisualStudio with GDB, allowing you to compile and debug without leaving VisualStudio. It's quite flexible, and is actively supported and developed.

Answer (score 6):

I used and loved `DDD` debugger (a GUI on top of the standard `gdb`) which felt very native and easy-to-learn coming from many years of MS VisualStudio environment.

You can do all those "standard" debugging tasks like drilling down into data structures with a mouse, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, etc.

It is called `Data Display Debugger` and you can find more info on it at the GNU website which also includes screenshots so you can quickly judge if this tool is right for you:
http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/

**2017 edit**:
The new MS Visual Studio 2017 (all editions, including the free one) now has a built-in Linux support which includes debugging Linux programs remotely with the MS VC's built-in debugger. That even includes the edit-and-continue support(!)

Here's a [video that demonstrates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIiFuBczd6A&t=204s) this

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [GNU `emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor to type -and even compile- your C++ code.

It can run the [`gdb` debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (for your C++ code you could [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` to get warnings and debug information), the [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) build automation tool, the [`git` version control](https://git-scm.com/) tool, etc etc...

If you need a graphical interface for `gdb` outside of emacs consider `xgdb` or `ddd`.